# How can I do a recursive query or subquery inside a query?

Tags: mysql, subquery, innodb

I'm not sure if I need exactly a recursive query but this is what I'm trying to do (an A query which calls a B query which calls an A query... recursively).

This is my minimal complete verifiable code:

I have a table like this (MySQL v5.7, InnoDB):

```
CREATE TABLE transactions 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    code VARCHAR(10),
    date DATETIME,
    mode ENUM('Buy', 'Sell', 'Count', 'Return'),
    quantity INT,
    price DECIMAL(10,2),
    price_currency ENUM('ARS', 'USD'),
    usd_to_ars DECIMAL(10,2),
    return_id INT NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

And then I populate it with some items:

```
INSERT INTO transactions (code, date, mode, quantity, price, price_currency, usd_to_ars) 
VALUES 
("a", "20180101", 'Buy', 4, 10, 'ARS', 3.7),
("a", "20180102", 'Buy', 9, 8, 'ARS', 5.8),
("a", "20180103", 'Sell', -3, 0, 'USD', 0),
("b", "20180104", 'Buy', 5, 5, 'USD', 8.9),
("a", "20180105", 'Buy', 2, 7, 'USD', 3.4),
("b", "20180106", 'Buy', 1, 8, 'ARS', 9),
("a", "20180107", 'Sell', -8, 0, 'USD', 4.4),
("a", "20180108", 'Buy', 9, 9, 'ARS', 3.2);

INSERT INTO transactions (code, date, mode, quantity, price, price_currency, usd_to_ars, return_id) 
VALUES ("a", "20180109", 'Return', 6, 2, 'ARS', 2, 2);
```

Finally I execute this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT
         id, date, code, mode, quantity, price, price_currency, usd_to_ars, return_id,
       @acm := @acm + quantity as stock,
       @avr := (@avr * (@acm - quantity) +
               if(quantity > 0, quantity *
                   if(mode = "Return", @avr,
                        if(price_currency = 'USD', price, price / usd_to_ars)
                     ),
                   quantity * @avr)
                 ) / @acm as average_price_usd
FROM
    transactions t1,
    (SELECT @acm := 0) x,
    (SELECT @avr := 0) y) t2
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6368f61a43c42782cfc10ff1943d664)

As you can see, it doesn't raise error, it returns a table, it works... but not like I want.

In the fourth line:

```
@avr := (@avr * (@acm - quantity) + if(quantity > 0, quantity * if(mode = "Return", @avr, if(price_currency = 'USD', price, price / usd_to_ars)), quantity * @avr)) / @acm as average_price_usd
```

I would like to change the `@avr` parameter of the:

```
If(mode = "Return", @avr, [...])
```

At the moment, if `mode = "Return"` is `true`, the current `@avr` value is used, but I would like to use the `@avr` value of the record where `id = return_id` instead. And due `@avr` is a calculated value I must to perform a sub query in order to calculate it again... I think. The problem is that I have no idea of how to do that.

[image]

So, the average price of the `id = 9` shouldn't be `3.02...`, instead, it should be something like `2.72...`.

So, how can I perform this query inside the other query when `mode = "Return"` in order to get the `@avr` value of the record `WHERE subquery.id = return_id`?

If it's possible to do, I'm new to SQL stuff, so I'm still not sure which things are possible and which ones are impossible. It doesn't matter for me if I need to make a column in the table, a view or a function, I think I can handle with either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Intro : your DB fiddle indicates that you seem to be using MySQL 8.0.

Since you already have a working query and you just need to handle the specific `mode = 'Return'` case, one solution could be to turn your query to a CTE, and self-join it to put Return records in relation with their original Buy.

This works in [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cf6KPoAFjaNGibrnBVfqyR/0) :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT
           id, date, code, mode, quantity, price, price_currency, usd_to_ars, return_id,
           @acm := @acm + quantity as stock,
           @avr := (@avr * (@acm - quantity) +
                   if(quantity > 0, quantity *
                       if(mode = "Return", @avr,
                            if(price_currency = 'USD', price, price / usd_to_ars)
                         ),
                       quantity * @avr)
                     ) / @acm as average_price_usd
    FROM
        transactions t1,
        (SELECT @acm := 0) x,
        (SELECT @avr := 0) y) t2
)
SELECT
    cte.id, 
    cte.date,
    cte.code,
    cte.mode,
    cte.quantity,
    cte.price,
    cte.price_currency,
    cte.usd_to_ars,
    cte.return_id,
    cte.stock,
    COALESCE(cte2.average_price_usd, cte.average_price_usd) average_price_usd
FROM cte LEFT JOIN cte cte2 ON cte.mode = 'Return' AND cte2.id = cte.return_id
ORDER BY cte.id DESC
```

Also, it seems like you probably also could achieve your goal using *MySQL 8.0 window functions*. The logic to compute `average_price_usd` is unclear to me, however here is a query that computes the stock using this technique. You maybe could modify it to add the logic for the average price (it should go to the CTE part of the above query) :

```
SELECT 
    id,
    code,
    date,
    mode,
    quantity,
    price,
    price_currency,
    usd_to_ars,
    return_id,
    SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY date) stock,
    NULL average_price_usd
FROM transactions
ORDER BY date desc
```

---

**EDIT** : here is an (ugly) workaround for MySQL < 8.0, using two subqueries (see [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cf6KPoAFjaNGibrnBVfqyR/2)) :

```
SELECT
    cte.id, 
    cte.date,
    cte.code,
    cte.mode,
    cte.quantity,
    cte.price,
    cte.price_currency,
    cte.usd_to_ars,
    cte.return_id,
    cte.stock,
    COALESCE(cte2.average_price_usd, cte.average_price_usd) average_price_usd
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            id, date, code, mode, quantity, price, price_currency, usd_to_ars, return_id,
            @acm := @acm + quantity as stock,
            @avr := (@avr * (@acm - quantity) +
                   if(quantity > 0, quantity *
                       if(mode = "Return", @avr,
                            if(price_currency = 'USD', price, price / usd_to_ars)
                         ),
                       quantity * @avr)
                     ) / @acm as average_price_usd
        FROM
            transactions t1,
            (SELECT @acm := 0) x,
            (SELECT @avr := 0) y
    ) cte
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            id, date, code, mode, quantity, price, price_currency, usd_to_ars, return_id,
            @acm2 := @acm2 + quantity as stock,
            @avr2 := (@avr2 * (@acm2 - quantity) +
                   if(quantity > 0, quantity *
                       if(mode = "Return", @avr2,
                            if(price_currency = 'USD', price, price / usd_to_ars)
                         ),
                       quantity * @avr2)
                     ) / @acm2 as average_price_usd
        FROM
            transactions t1,
            (SELECT @acm2 := 0) x,
            (SELECT @avr2 := 0) y
    ) cte2 ON cte.mode = 'Return' AND cte2.id = cte.return_id
ORDER BY cte.id DESC
```

Comment: In DBfiddle I use MySQL v8.0 because there isn't an option to use MySQL v5.7. My database is in a MySQL v5.7 server. Right now is late, but tomorrow I will check your answer to see if it can solve my problem.

Comment: 1) You code replaces the `average_price_usd` with the value of the entry `Where cte.mode = 'Return' AND cte2.id = cte.return_id`. Instead, I need to calculate it **using** that value. I.e: `@avr := (@avr * (@acm - quantity) + if(quantity > 0, quantity * if(mode = "Return", THAT_VALUE, if(price_currency = 'USD', price, price / usd_to_ars) ), quantity * @avr) ) / @acm as average_price_usd`. 2) I didn't use `SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY date) stock` because it's perfomance expensive than my current approach, isn't it? 3) BTW, I've tested it, and `WITH` isn't recogniced in MYSQL v5.7, which I use.

Comment: And yes, MySQL v5.7 is an old version, but the server use that :(

Comment: @EnderLook : neither `WITH` nor window functions (`SUM() OVER()`) are supported in MySQL 5.7. I updated my answer with a query for your version (also see the db fiddle).

Comment: Thanks, that code works in 5.7, but your code still replaces `average_price_usd` instead of do what I said in the point (1) of my previous comment. I tried to solve that changing the last line of the first select (that `COALESCE`) with `if(cte2.average_price_usd > 0, ((cte.stock - cte.quantity) * cte.average_price_usd + cte.quantity * cte2.average_price_usd) / cte.stock, cte.average_price_usd) average_price_usd`. But, 1) If `cte2.average_price_usd > 0` isn't true (even if `mode = Return`) it doesn't work, when it should. 2) That isn't recursive, the next entry wouldn't be made from this value.